# React Native Video poster not working in ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to add a poster image in the react-native-video library. In android, it works fine but in the iOS poster, the image shows for 1-2 seconds and then getting disappeared.

My react-native version is 0.63.3.

Below is my code.

```
        <Video
          style={this.props.styles.video}
          source={{
            uri: !this.state.isEnabled
              ? this.props.url
              : this.props.caption_url,
          }}
          // Can be a URL or a local file.
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.player = ref;
          }}
          poster={this.props.poster}
          paused={this.state.paused}
          muted={this.state.muted}
          controls={this.props.controls}
          resizeMode={'cover'}
          // resizeMode={'stretch'}
          fullscreen={true}
          onLoad={this.handleLoad}
          onProgress={this.handleProgress}
          onEnd={this.handleEnd}
          fullscreen={this.state.fullscreen}
          onError={(error) => {
            console.log(error, 'THIS IS ERROR');
          }}
        />
```